# Traverse and print nested JSON data

Tags: json

I have a file with JSON data in a nested format. I want to traverse through this data and output it in the form of a JQuery listview but am unable to do so.

The JSON data is in this format:

```
{
  "Name":"A",
  "Company": "B",
  "Address": {
    "Street":"ABC",
    "City":"XYZ"
  }
}
```

I tried the following:

```
$.each(data, function(key,value) {
   $('#companyDetails').append('<li>'+key+'<span class="ui-li-aside">'+value+'</span></li>');
});
```

but this does not output the 'Address' block properly.

Comment: What kind of outcome do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the most efficient way of doing this but I think it does what you want.

Assumptions: Data is an array, with each array element being an object (hash). Tested in Chrome on Windows only.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function read_record(data) {
            $.each(data, function(key,value) {
                if ($.isPlainObject(value))
                    read_record(value);
                else
                    $('#details').append('<li>' + key + ' = ' + value + '</li>');
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            var data = [
                {
                    "Name" : "John",
                    "Company" : "Doe",
                    "Address" : {
                        "Street" : "123 Main Street",
                        "City" : "San Francisco"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Name" : "Jane",
                    "Company" : "Johnson",
                    "Address" : {
                        "Street" : "57 Heinz Lane",
                        "City" : "Dallas"
                    }
                }           
            ];

            read_record(data);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="details"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Produces:

- Name = John
- Company = Doe
- Street = 123 Main Street
- City = San Francisco
- Name = Jane
- Company = Johnson
- Street = 57 Heinz Lane
- City = Dallas

Answer (score 3):

How about using **value.Address.City** and **value.Address.Street**?? The most common way to access JSON data is through dot notation. This is simply the object name followed by a period and then followed by the name/property you would like to access. http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_JSON_%28_JavaScript_Object_Notation_%29

For example,

```
$.each(data, function(key,value) {
    $('#companyDetails').append('<li>'+key+'<span class="ui-li-aside">'+ value.Address.Street + "," + value.Address.City +'</span></li>');
});
```

For detail coding,

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function display(data) {
            $.each(data, function(key,value) {
                $('#companyDetails').append('<li>'+key+'<span class="ui-li-aside">'+ value.Address.Street + "," + value.Address.City +'</span></li>');
            });
        }
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var data = [
                {
                    "Name" : "ABC",
                    "Company" : "AA Company",
                    "Address" : {
                        "Street" : "123 Main Street",
                        "City" : "Yangon"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Name" : "DEF",
                    "Company" : "BB Company",
                    "Address" : {
                        "Street" : "8941 Mandalay",
                        "City" : "NaypiDaw"
                    }
                }           
            ];
        display(data);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="companyDetails"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

For you case that you do not know which data are in json file,

```
function display(data,flag) {
    $.each(data, function(key,value) {
    if ($.isPlainObject(value)) {
        if(flag == true)
        {
            $('#companyDetails').append('<b>' + "Company " + (key + 1) + '</b>');
        }
        display(value,false);
    }
    else
        $('#companyDetails').append('<li>' + key +  " : " +'<span class="ui-li-aside">'+ value +'</span></li>');
    });
}
```

In calling display function,

```
var flag = true;
display(data,flag);
```

Your output would be
[image]I hope this would help.

Comment: This absolutely works AS IS. This should be your accepted answer.

Comment: No, this is when I know what data is present inside my JSON file. I want to write a function that simply outputs/prints all the values inside the JSON file. I need not know what type of data is present or what the value of each key is. I hope you got my question now.

Comment: I know what you mean, but I want to know your expected format to show.