# Traverse nested Object Literal data

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, nested, traversal, object-literal

Been looking through the forums and none of the solutions that I have seen have worked for my case unless I am doing it wrong. I am trying to list out data for different states that is connected to a jQuery map plugin. Basically the user will click a state and the state laws will append underneath the map. Right now my JSON tree looks like:

```
var states = {
   "AL" : {
       "longname" : "Alabama",
       "lawOne" : "Text for Law 1",
       "lawTwo" : "Text for Law 2",
       "lawThree" : "Text for Law 3"
   },
   "AK" : {
       "longname" : "Alaska",
       "lawOne" : "Text for Law 1",
       "lawTwo" : "Text for Law 2",
       "lawThree" : "Text for Law 3"
   },
   etc...
}
```

Using the answer to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12047950/traverse-and-print-nested-json-data), I can dive into tier 2 nested Data, but the entry point for the state seems to be the hold up. I need the abbreviated state name because that is the data that the map API spits out when a state is clicked. Any idea of what other steps might need to be implemented in order to make this work? Seems like there are no answers for finding an object within an object. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I found the exact answer I was looking for once I realized I was clumsy and that this was an Object Literal, and not JSON. I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key)

Comment: That is not JSON. That is a JavaScript object literal. The terms are not interchangeable.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated the question and posted the answer I found

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the abbreviated name which is defined as properties of `state` object.

```js
var states = {
   "AL" : {
       "longname" : "Alabama",
       "lawOne" : "Text for Law 1",
       "lawTwo" : "Text for Law 2",
       "lawThree" : "Text for Law 3"
   },
   "AK" : {
       "longname" : "Alaska",
       "lawOne" : "Text for Law 1",
       "lawTwo" : "Text for Law 2",
       "lawThree" : "Text for Law 3"
   }
}

console.log(Object.keys(states))
```

Comment: This gets me a lit of the states in the array, but how would I be able to focus in on one (dynamically) and grab a value from inside given state?

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate and get short name like this:

```
var states = {
   "AL" : {
       "longname" : "Alabama",
       "lawOne" : "Text for Law 1",
       "lawTwo" : "Text for Law 2",
       "lawThree" : "Text for Law 3"
   },
   "AK" : {
       "longname" : "Alaska",
       "lawOne" : "Text for Law 1",
       "lawTwo" : "Text for Law 2",
       "lawThree" : "Text for Law 3"
   }
}

for (var key in states) {
  if (states.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    var val = states[key];
    console.log(key + ':' + val.longname);
  }
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/12bor11u/1/

Comment: I believe this is more along the lines I am looking for for sure. The only problem is that the State abbreviation is Dynamic in nature and I will need to figure out how to input that data dynamically. That's on me to figure out though. I appreciate the head start!